# How to calculate the sum of all featured thumbnail height on Wordpress?

Tags: post-thumbnails, gallery

In an archive page, I need to calculate the **total height** of a  which is the container of many featured thumbnails, knowing that all the featured thumbnails have **different heights** (but the same width) and knowing that the thumbnail will be displayed in three column which means that I have to divide the sum by three.

```
<div class="container">
<img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="300" />
<img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="500" />
<img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="450" />
…
</div>
```

I think that the way to calculate it is to retrieve the featured thumbnails heights within the loop and then to add all of them. But, how to do it precisely ?

What I aim is to create a gallery which contains all my featured thumbnail displayed in three column of the same size, like the Flick way but with a vertical alignment.

Maybe I'm trying to reinvent the wheel and there is a plugin that automatically does it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I aim is to create a gallery which contains all my featured thumbnail displayed in three column of the same size, like the Flick way but with a vertical alignment.

Did you try [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/)? It's a JavaScript library that can help you create the gallery without the need to calculate the height of each image.

If you decided to use masonry.js, you may need to use [images-loaded.js](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) in order to help masonry.js deal with images dimensions correctly.

Comment: I will try this solution : thanks for putting me on a track !